# select 2 not calling ajax function in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

view:

```
 <select class="js-data-example-ajax" id="tag_list">
   <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select customer</option>
 </select>
```

ajax:

```
$('#tag_list').select2({
        placeholder: 'Enter a tag',
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '{{ url("api/tags") }}',
            delay: 400,
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    term: params.term
                }
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
              return {
                results: data
              };
            },
        }
});
```

I am using select 2 in Laravel. The ajax function is not calling in the view page. I have placed the ajax code at the bottom of the page. But the ajax function is not calling. But I have checked the data from controller using postman.The data is returning in the controller.

Comment: Does your returned data include id and name fields? Did you check in the Network tab of Chrome's devtools if the ajax request is being done?